# Dictionary of Lists

Tags: c#

I'm trying to build a dictionary of lists, but i'm reading in a string and need to make the lists name the string and add them to the dictionary as a key.

IE read in "hello"

Create the list with what was read in

```
List<string> (insert read string here ) = new List<string>();
```

Then add that lists name as the key to a dictionary.

```
Dictionary.Add(readstring, thatlist);
```

---

All I can find is a hard code implementation of this.

```
Turing.Add("S", S);
```

My goal: create a Universal Turing Machine, so I read in an input from a text file that is the next step that looks like this, (q0 a) -> q1 X R.

Then use the all the steps that I read in to end in a final state with this on the virtual tape "tape = XXYYZZBB"

I have the the pseudo code written for this but I just cant get the dictionary to work.

EDIT:
Adding some more info for less confusion.
Im given the start and the end state for the first 2 lines of the text file. Then im given the transitions.

q0 //start state
q5 //end state
q0 a q1 X R //transitions

Ive stripped the first two lines of input to give me 0 and 5 then have created a for loop to create a lists of each state.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= endState; i++)
{
List<string> i = new List<string>();
}
```

I then want to add each lists name as a key to the dictionary of lists I am creating.

```
Dictionary.Add(listname, thatlist);
```

I need help on implementing the code for the above as its giving errors.

Comment: It's very hard to understand your requirement.

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't matter whether you create your list as

```
List<string> insertReadStringHere = new List<string>();
```

or

```
List<string> foo = new List<string>();
```

or even

```
List<string> shellBeComingRoundTheMountain = new List<string>();
```

What's important is that once you've done

```
MyDictionary.Add(theInputString, shellBeComingRoundTheMountain);
```

you can then access that particular list via

```
MyDictionary[theInputString]
```

wherether the initial list was "called" `insertReadStringHere` or `foo` or `shellBeComingRoundTheMountain`.

You don't even need to hold the list in a named variable like this. For example,

```
Console.WriteLine("Input a string to create a list:");
var createListName = Console.ReadLine();
// As long as they haven't used the string before...
MyDictionary.Add(createListName, new List<string>());

Console.WriteLine("Input a string to retrieve a list:");
var retrieveListName = Console.ReadLine();
// As long as they input the same string...
List<string> retrievedList = MyDictionary[retrieveListName];
```

Edit: If you want a certain number of lists, use a dictionarym apping from *int* to string, not string to string:

```
int maxNumberOfLists = 5; // or whatever you read from your text file.
Dictionary<int, List<string>> myLists =
            new Dictionary<int, List<string>> (maxNumberOfLists);
for (int i = 1; i <= maxNumberOfLists; i++)
    myLists[i] = new List<string>();
```

Then you can access your lists as e.g.

```
var firstList = myLists[1];
```

Ordinarily I'd recommend an array, but this gives you lists from 1 to 5 rather than from 0 to 4 and it seems that's what you want.

Comment: So I am trying to create a list of each numerical value 1, 2, ... n where the text file I am reading in gives me the max states I would have. So say the text file has 5 max states I would want to create a list for each numerical number 1, 2, 3,...etc.

for (int i = 0; i <= endState; i++)
{
List<string> i = new List<string>();
}

Comment: @MechaMan I've added some code for if you want to access your lists by number.